# How to construct a container of MyClass, where MyClass constructor can throw?

Tags: c++, exception, constructor

I have something like:

```
#include "MyImage.hpp"  // MyImage wraps the Qt library image class
namespace fs = boost::filesystem;
class ImageCollection {
public:
  ImageCollection(const char* path);
private:
  const fs::path path_;
  deque<MyImage> instanceDeque_;
}

ImageCollection(const char* path) :
  path_(fs::is_directory(path) ?
        fs::complete(path) :
        fs::complete(path).parent_path()) /* Can I even do this? */
{
  /***   code in question   ***/
  fs::directory_iterator endIter;
  for(fs::directory_iterator dirIter(path_); dirIter != endIter; dirIter++) {
    instanceDeque_.push_back(MyImage(*dirIter));
  }
}
```

The MyImage constructor throws a MyInvalidFileException when *dirIter is a fs::path to a non-image file.

I'd like MyImage and ImageCollection to be immutable.

Can I:

```
try {
  instanceDeque_.push_back(MyImage(*dirIter));
}
catch(const MyInvalidFileException& e) {  // oops, tnx Nemanja T.
  // remember *dirIter in a list of non-Image files, to use later
  continue;
}
```

What happens when it throws? Is there a zombie MyImage or a zombie element left in the deque? Or is this actually the right way to do it? (i.e. the push_back() is aborted and no MyImage is created.)

I currently have a messy workaround:

```
// load up an empty MyImage, which I'd rather not do
instanceDeque_.push_back(MyImage());
for(fs::directory_iterator dirIter(path_); dirIter != endIter; dirIter++) {
  MyImage& attemptImage = instanceDeque_.back();
  bool success = attemptImage.loadPath(*dirIter); // "fill" the empty MyImage
  if (success)
    instanceDeque_.push_back(MyImage()); // prepare another empty MyImage
}
instanceDeque_.pop_back(); // discard the empty MyImage
```

Where MyImage is initialized with a null QImage*, and loadPath() creates a QImage on the heap. This forces me to have null pointer checks everywhere. I figure there should be a way to have an instance of QImage if the file can be opened, and the construction to just fail if the file can't.

Comment: Catch by const reference, not by value.

Comment: Why are you using Boost to manage paths when QDir and friends are right there?

Also deque is kind of useless, as QList performs very good in many cases and provides a cleaner and easier to use API.

Comment: How is the QList interface better? It looks exactly the same to me.

Comment: Why must the image constructor throw an exception? It could simply create a "null" image, like QImage does.

Comment: For (i'm guessing) typical reasons, I want to use STL as much as possible, and then Boost, and then Qt. Besides, I've learned a lot about dealing with external libraries for C++ programming by doing this.

@rpg - "null" is what I'm already doing, but not only does it require me to handle the null case, I've no need for a null image at all. I'm not going to change the image later. I want to design this so that if QImage can't open the image, then never construct and never insert into the container in the first place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on `MyImage` I guess. If there is an exception in the constructor of MyImage it should fail before you even reach the `push_back` method. This is because the constructor will be run before the `push_back` (which is logical, since it needs a value to pass the method). Thus if that step fails and exception is thrown, `push_back` will never be reached.

Here are some pointers:

- [C++ FAQ Lite: How can I handle a
  constructor that fails?](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/exceptions.html#faq-17.2)
- [C++ FAQ
  Lite: How should I handle resources
  if my constructors may throw
  exceptions?](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/exceptions.html#faq-17.4)

Answer (score 1):

If `MyImage(*dirIter)` fails you will not get into `push_back` so that's not a problem.

Answer (score 1):

As others have already mention, if the `MyImage` constructor throws then you'll never reach the `deque.push_back` function so that will not be a problem.  Also if it does make it into the `push_back` function and it throws for some reason, then your deque object will remain unchanged.  The STL does not allow methods to modify/corrupt the container if the operation fails.  I couldn't find anything about `push_back` throwing in the [documentation](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/Deque.html), so you probably don't have to worry about that unless you run out of memory or some other extreme case.